# determine if sheet change is in particular row

Tags: vba, excel

I want to determine if a change to a sheet includes cells in one particular row.  I tried

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim i As Integer

    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Yahoo" Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range(Cells([YahooID_Row], 1), Cells([YahooID_Row], 999))) Is Nothing Then

        Else

        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

YahooID_Row is a named integer constant.

I keep getting run time error 1004.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the strategy you have tried, here's a working version of your code

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Sh.Name = "Yahoo" Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Rows([YahooID_Row])) Is Nothing Then

        Else

        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

The differfences are

1. Check the the `Sh` parameter rather than the active sheet.  The change that triggered the Event may not be from the ActiveSheet.
2. Qualify the sheet reference (`Range(...`) to `Sh`
3. Since `[YahooID_Row]` is a named constant (rather than a named range) use it as an index
4. Check whole rows rather than just the first 999 columns

Comment: Great! Thanks.  Just out of curiosity how can I make an explicit Range using named constant row and cell numbers?  For example, let's say I want to know if something in column [c] from row [ra] to [rb] has changed.  From above answers I see how I could do this with a series of Ifs but can I make a range?

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you are only interested in which row the changes occur in (and don't care about the column). It finds the first and last row in the range object and checks if `YahooID_Row` is between them.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    dim firstRow, lastRow as double    
    firstRow = target.Rows(1).Row
    lastRow = target.Rows(target.Rows.Count).Row
    if (YahooID_Row >= firstRow and YahooID_Row =< lastRow) then
        msgbox "Change in the YahooID row"
    end if

End Sub
```

You could also move the first/last row declarations and calculations directly into the `if` statement, if you would prefer to eliminate the additional lines of code.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    if (YahooID_Row >= target.Rows(1).Row and YahooID_Row =< target.Rows(target.Rows.Count).Row) then
        msgbox "Change in the YahooID row"
    end if

End Sub
```

Comment: But I want to know if Target is a range that includes cells in row YahooID_Row.

Comment: Sorry I didn't state the problem as clearly as I should have.  I changed the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single sheet then you can simply check the intersect between the Row and target directly using `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`. If there are multiple sheets then only use `Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)`

The below code code goes in the worksheet code area where you want to do the check. `

Also if you are planning to write to a cell then ensure that you set `Application.EnableEvents = False` to prevent possible endless loop and also use proper error handling to set it to `True` again.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Dim YahooID_Row As Long

    '~~> Row 5
    YahooID_Row = 5

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Rows(YahooID_Row)) Is Nothing Then
        '
        '~~> You rest of the code goes here
        '
    End If

LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```